# how to reference datatable names

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

Rather than referencing `0` and `1` for my rows. How do I reference the name of the columns in my data table?

```
txtCustomerRef.Text = dobj.GetCustomerData(selectedValue).Rows[0][0].ToString();
txtCustomerName.Text = dobj.GetCustomerData(selectedValue).Rows[1][1].ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the column name for your columns:

```
txtCustomerRef.Text = dobj.GetCustomerData(selectedValue).Rows[0]["CustomerRef"].ToString();
txtCustomerName.Text = dobj.GetCustomerData(selectedValue).Rows[1]["CustomerName"].ToString();
```